# ios access payload profile in app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to access a payload profile in iOS within an app?

We want to roll out an App with BES12 & therefore we can send a payload profile to every phone which contains user credentials.

We would need those information in the app & therefore we need to read this profile somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> You can define a custom Access Point Name (APN) for cellular data
>   access using either of two different configuration profile payloads –
>   APN or Cellular. Only the Cellular payload works in iOS 9.0, but both
>   payloads work in iOS 9.0.1. If you have a profile that uses an APN
>   payload, you should update your device to iOS 9.0.1 to maintain
>   cellular data access.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT205222

**Note:** If a feature is controlled by an existing BES12 policy or profile, a custom payload profile may not work as expected. You should use existing policies or profiles whenever possible.

You can also use this :- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Maybe my question was not clear. Ok, we do send a custom payload file to an iphone. Now I make my app and would like to get the data form this custom payload file (like username). Do you know if that's possbile?

Comment: Did you mean sending custom payload file, while sending push notification to a user?

Comment: I'm not sure how or when the custom payload file is sent to the user. Let's pretend the user has his payload file already on the phone. Now he opens the app. And in this app I want to see info from the payload file. Is that possible?